# Rotation formula deforming polygons

Tags: javascript, html, rotation, geometry, trigonometry

I have written myself a formula to rotate the points of regular polygons (and maybe even irregular) around an orientation point. The formula seems to work on discretely coded rectangles:

```
tempShape.points = [[0,0],[wid,0],[wid,hig],[0,hig]];
```

But not on polygons generated by formula:

```
tempShape.points = [[len,0]];
for(var i=1; i < poin; i++){
    if(gen){
        tempShape.points[i] = [0,0];
        tempShape.points[i][0] = len*Math.cos(angle*i);
        tempShape.points[i][1] = len*Math.sin(angle*i);
    }
}
```

This is my rotation formula:

```
    for(var i2 = 0; i2 < displayList[i].points.length; i2++){
        displayList[i].points[i2][0] = (displayList[i].pointsRot[i2][0] + displayList[i].oPoint[0]) * Math.cos(displayList[i].rotation) - (displayList[i].pointsRot[i2][1] + displayList[i].oPoint[1]) * Math.sin(displayList[i].rotation);
        displayList[i].points[i2][1] = (displayList[i].pointsRot[i2][1] + displayList[i].oPoint[1]) * Math.cos(displayList[i].rotation) + (displayList[i].pointsRot[i2][0] + displayList[i].oPoint[0]) * Math.sin(displayList[i].rotation);
    }
```

Where displayList[i] is the shape, .points is the array containing all the points, .rotation is the rotation of the shape, .oPoint is the point of orientation.
I hope you can help, thanks in advance.
Kyle.

Edit:
Just tried rather than incrementing the rotation I set a static rotation of 0.01, but this makes it act like it would normally if incremented the rotation by 0.01, so somewhere (I don't know where) it must be like incrementing my rotation by the set rotation, I just need to figure it out. Could I give my whole code for someone to look through to help me?

Answer (score 1):

*You are using in the second formula value `displayList[i].pointsRot[i2][0]` which has been already changed in the first formula. Just remember original value in temporary variable and use it.*

**Edit:** It seems I was entangled in your longlonglong names.
Сheck that your formulas match to:

```
  NewX = CenterX + (OldX-CenterX)*Cos(Fi) - (OldY-CenterY)*Sin(Fi)
  NewY = CenterY + (OldX-CenterX)*Sin(Fi) + (OldY-CenterY)*Cos(Fi)
```

where (CenterX, CenterY) is point of rotation

Comment: It hasn't been changed in the first formula; I changed displayList[i].points[i2][0] not displayList[i].pointsRot[i2][0] For this specific reason. Also you put temp as displayList[i].points[i2][0] and not .pointsRot[i2][0] so your example wouldn't work anyway, thanks for trying though.

Comment: Tried your assumption, still doesn't work. I don't know why these work on the discretely coded rectangles and not the generated shapes (even squares) though.

Comment: Also without the rotate script it shows up as a normal square (or whatever shape specified) but with the script it just shows a line of seemingly random length.

Comment: Why polygon generation cycle starts with 1? `for(var i=1`

Comment: I needed the first real point to be (length, 0) not (0,0): tempShape.points = [[len,0]];

Comment: and what is relation between tempshape and displayList?

Comment: tempShape is used in the function to create the polygon (and is returned at the end of the function), this is then assigned to a variable, and the variable is added to the displayList array

Comment: You have to debug your code and find errors in coordinates and what causes them...